# NumPy equivalent to random.getrandbits()

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm working on creating a subclass of [`random.Random()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) where the generator is actually NumPy's default [Random Generator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html).

The reason for this is, I can leverage parallel execution using NumPy's generator via the [SeedSequence](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/parallel.html#seedsequence-spawning) object.

Overriding methods `random()` and `seed()` is fairly easy, however, I also need to override method [`getrandbits()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.getrandbits), but I haven't been able to find any Numpy's equivalent function/solution. `getrandbits()` is used heavily by all other functions of class `random.Random()`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to subclass stdlib random generators?

Comment: you can take a look at the source for [`random.getrandbits`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4cfb10979d74b8513ec751b81454709f38e3b51a/Lib/random.py#L826-L832) and port that to numpy

Comment: @jakub indeed, my thinking is however there's an easier solution in front of my eyes and I just don't see it. Looking at the code, it boils down to replicate `int.from_bytes(_urandom(numbytes), 'big')`. Will work on that if I don't get the easier, expected answer.

Comment: @AndrasDeak The ultimate goal is to use that subclass for creating faker.Faker objects. All functions in Faker use the underlying Random generator, specifically the functions `random()` and `getrandbits()`. Class random.Random() however cannot be parallelized and the BitGenerator cannot be advanced ([PCG64 can](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/generated/numpy.random.PCG64.advance.html#numpy.random.PCG64.advance)).

Comment: @jakub This could be the gist of the solution, unless there's a simpler, higher level function.  `int.from_bytes(np.random.default_rng().bytes(numbytes), 'big')`. Thanks!

Comment: I'd assume if there were bit-level methods they would be mentioned at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.bytes.html. Numpy's geared at larger scales than bytes, rather than smaller. So it's all plausible to me.

Answer (score 1):

As @jakub mentioned in the comments, easiest way is to port the source code to NumPy.

```py
    def getrandbits(self, k):
        print()
        """getrandbits(k) -> x.  Generates an int with k random bits."""
        if k < 0:
            raise ValueError('number of bits must be non-negative')
        numbytes = (k + 7) // 8                       # bits / 8 and rounded up
        x = int.from_bytes(self.rng.bytes(numbytes), 'big')
        return x >> (numbytes * 8 - k)                # trim excess bits
```

where `self.rng` is an instance of `np.random.Generator`.

Comment: you could also do something similar with a raw `BitGenerator` as it returns a `uint64` `ndarray`, e.g. `int.from_bytes(bitgen.random_raw(num_u64s, 'big'))`